# Add vertical slider to product page (view more images)

Tags: product-view, slider

I am searching for a vertical slider for my product page. I tried http://codepen.io/thirdender/pen/aOYyGb but it doesn't work. Any other solution?

Comment: can  you used the owl.carousel.js

Answer (score 3):

You must create the `view.xml` file on your theme `app/design/frontend/VendorPackage/Theme/etc/view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <vars module="Magento_Catalog">
        <var name="gallery">
            <var name="navdir">vertical</var>
        </var>
    </vars>
</view>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code can help you

http://codepen.io/syaaoo/pen/OWeQZV

I'm using jssor-slider

**HTML :**

```
 <html>
    <div id="jssor_1" style="position:relative;margin:0 auto;top:0px;left:0px;width:600px;height:300px;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;">
            <!-- Loading Screen -->
            <div data-u="loading" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);">
                <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
                <div style="position:absolute;display:block;background:url('img/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
            </div>
            <div data-u="slides" style="cursor:default;position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;width:600px;height:300px;overflow:hidden;">
                <div>
                    <img data-u="image" src="http://placehold.it/600x300/ff9500/ffffff?text=Slide%200" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img data-u="image" src="http://placehold.it/600x300/ff9500/ffffff?text=Slide%201" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img data-u="image" src="http://placehold.it/600x300/ff9500/ffffff?text=Slide%202" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img data-u="image" src="http://placehold.it/600x300/ff9500/ffffff?text=Slide%203" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Arrow Navigator -->
            <span data-u="arrowleft" class="jssora08l" style="top:8px;left:8px;width:50px;height:50px;" data-autocenter="1"></span>
            <span data-u="arrowright" class="jssora08r" style="bottom:8px;right:8px;width:50px;height:50px;" data-autocenter="1"></span>
        </div>
    </html>
```

**CSS :**

```
.jssora08l, .jssora08r {
            z-index:333;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            /* size of arrow element */
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            cursor: pointer;
            background: url('http://www.jssor.com/theme/img/a08.png') no-repeat;
            overflow: hidden;
            opacity: .4;
            filter: alpha(opacity=40);
        }
        .jssora08l { background-position: -5px -35px; }
        .jssora08r { background-position: -65px -35px; }
        .jssora08l:hover { background-position: -5px -35px; opacity: .8; filter:alpha(opacity=80); }
        .jssora08r:hover { background-position: -65px -35px; opacity: .8; filter:alpha(opacity=80); }
        .jssora08l.jssora08ldn { background-position: -5px -35px; opacity: .3; filter:alpha(opacity=30); }
        .jssora08r.jssora08rdn { background-position: -65px -35px; opacity: .3; filter:alpha(opacity=30); }
        .jssora08l.jssora08lds { background-position: -5px -35px; opacity: .3; pointer-events: none; }
        .jssora08r.jssora08rds { background-position: -65px -35px; opacity: .3; pointer-events: none; }

*{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  background-color:#fff;
  font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif,arial,helvetica,verdana;
}
```

**JS :**

```
    var jssor_1_options = {
      $AutoPlay: false,
      $DragOrientation: 2,
      $PlayOrientation: 2,
      $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
        $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
      }
    };

    var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);

    /*responsive code begin*/
    /*you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizing*/
    function ScaleSlider() {
        var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
        if (refSize) {
            refSize = Math.min(refSize, 600);
            jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
        }
        else {
            window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }
    }
    ScaleSlider();
    $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
    /*responsive code end*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the the file

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/etc/view.xml

We can see a variable **navdir**.

This variable has ability to change the thumbnails alignment in Fotorama.

By default it is set as:

```
<var name="navdir"> horizontal</var>
```

Change the code like this:

```
<var name="navdir"> vertical</var>
```

to make the thumbnails as vertical.